# Height is giving me a broken image link OVER my image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, height

What I'm trying to do it have my picture as a button and I've been using the 'input type"image"' for it and it's been going fine and dandy until I tried changing the height of my picture, width is all cool to change but height.. Nuhu.

Here's the code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
       .startavisningstop
{
display:        block; 
margin-top:     0px;
background:     url("https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/102x24q90/822/kac9.png") no-repeat center center;
width:          102px;
height:         24px;

}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="image" value="&nbsp;" class="startavisningstop" onclick="location.href='latest_inlog_include.php?action=stoppa'"> 
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not using the green picture as a background on my site but I'm on a computer that doesn't allow uploads so hence why I'm using the green picture in the example.
I'm using a picture that's got the dimensions 102px width and 24px height.
As you can see, I can freely change the width but when I add a height line it gives me a transparent broken image picture on top of my own picture.

P.S. If anyone knows any better way to do this I'm all good with some tips, seeing as it doesn't look very appealing right now.

Comment: It works kwel http://jsfiddle.net/VB4HS/?

Comment: This sounds unlikely to happen. can you upload the exact image you are using to any of the online file hosting services?

Comment: Wow, that's really strange, when I've got it up on my web page and when I tried it in the W3Schools editor it gives me a broken transparent link ontop but it's indeed working without any problems over at jsfiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a button instead of your input tag:

```
<button class="startavisningstop" onclick="location.href='latest_inlog_include.php?action=stoppa'"></button>

.startavisningstop {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Auto_Racing_Green.svg/800px-Auto_Racing_Green.svg.png") no-repeat center center;
    width: 102px;
    height: 24px;
    border:0;
}
```